# CONTROL \ crashes call to getline

Tags: c, gcc, crash, cygwin, getline

The following code produces "**Quit (core dumped)**" when I run it and type control \.  I don't even get to hit return.  I got this code from a tutorial book.

I tried debugging with gcc but it does this:  (At the blank line it's running getline and I'm typing control \.)

> 14        bytes_read = getline (&my_string, &nbytes, stdin); (gdb)
>
> Program received signal SIGQUIT, Quit. 0x004011e5 in main () at
>   myfile.c:14 14        bytes_read = getline (&my_string, &nbytes,
>   stdin); (gdb)

...when I single step it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
   int bytes_read;
   int nbytes = 100;
   char *my_string;

   puts ("Please enter a line of text.");

   /* These 2 lines are the heart of the program. */

  my_string = (char *) malloc (nbytes + 1);
  bytes_read = getline (&my_string, &nbytes, stdin);

   if (bytes_read == -1)
     {
       puts ("ERROR!");
     }
   else
     {
       puts ("You typed:");
       puts (my_string);
     }

   return 0;
}
```

I used command-line "gcc -g myfile.c".
I am on Cygwwin  bash

> $ uname --all CYGWIN_NT-5.1 LENOVO-3AA1E185 1.7.29(0.272/5/3)
>   2014-04-07 13:44 i686 Cygwin
>
> $ gcc -v Using built-in specs. COLLECT_GCC=gcc
>   COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/lto-wrapper.exe
>   Target: i686-pc-cygwin Configured with:
>   /cygdrive/i/szsz/tmpp/gcc4/gcc-4.8.2-2/src/gcc-4.8.2/configure
>   --srcdir=/cygdrive/i/szsz/tmpp/gcc4/gcc-4.8.2-2/src/gcc-4.8.2 --prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --sbindir=/usr/sbin --libexecdir=/usr/libexec --datadir=/usr/share --localstatedir=/var --sysconfdir=/etc --libdir=/usr/lib --datarootdir=/usr/share --docdir=/usr/share/doc/gcc --htmldir=/usr/share/doc/gcc/html -C --build=i686-pc-cygwin --host=i686-pc-cygwin --target=i686-pc-cygwin --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --enable-shared --enable-shared-libgcc --enable-static --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-bootstrap --disable-__cxa_atexit --with-dwarf2 --with-arch=i686 --with-tune=generic --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-languages=ada,c,c++,fortran,java,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-graphite --enable-threads=posix --enable-libatomic --enable-libgomp --disable-libitm --enable-libquadmath --enable-libquadmath-support --enable-libssp --enable-libada --enable-libjava --enable-libgcj-sublibs --disable-java-awt --disable-symvers --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/ecj.jar --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --with-cloog-include=/usr/include/cloog-isl --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib Thread model: posix gcc version 4.8.2 (GCC)

underneath cygwin is Microsoft Windows XP Professional 32-bit SP3

Answer (score 2):

Control-C is a Quit Signal trigger on most systems :

> The SIGQUIT signal is similar to SIGINT, except that it's controlled
>   by a different key—the QUIT character, usually C-\—and produces a core
>   dump when it terminates the process, just like a program error signal.
>   You can think of this as a program error condition “detected” by the
>   user.

[quoted from GNU](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Signals.html). So this behavior is expected: You program did receive the SIGQUIT signal

Comment: Thank you; that's very informative.  Is this the same as typing control-C but with the excitement of a core dump?  Can I catch these signals and be more silent?

Comment: Yes you can put a signal handler (see this example: http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/C++Signals.html) Don't forget to accept correct answers on StackOverflow.